# Splitting a String in Java with underscore as delimiter

Tags: java, string, split

I have the following String (This format for the string is generic)

```
abc_2012-10-18-05-37-23_prasad_hv_Complete
```

I want to extract only `prasad_hv`. How do i go about this?

This is not the only string i want to perform this operation on, so anything specific to this string (say, checking for 'prasad_hv') will not help.

I tried using split with `_` as the delimiter, but it splits `prasad` and `hv` separately. Please help!

P.S. to generalize, the string would follow the format

```
string_<digit>-<digit>-<digit>-<digit>-<digit>-<digit>_<String with underscores>_<String>
```

Comment: Is _complete always would be at the end of every string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work even when you have many number of underscore characters in the string you wanted.

```
str.substring(str.indexOf("_", str.indexOf("_") + 1) + 1, str.lastIndexOf("_"));
```

Answer (score 12):

You say

> This format for the string is generic.

Then concatenate the elements with indexes 2 and 3 after splitting:

```
String str = "abc_2012-10-18-05-37-23_prasad_hv_Complete";
String[] parts = str.split("_");
String extractedResult = "";
if(parts.length > 3)
   extractedResult = parts[2] + "_" + parts[3]; // prasad_hv is captured here.
```

Comment: this won't work if more _ characters are there, which seems to be the case per OP's description

Comment: Worked too! Thanks, but yeah, will not work in case more underscores are there.

Comment: @Reddy but the OP says the format is generic, i understood that it will be like abc(underscore)(a date)(underscore)(value1)(underscore)(value2)(underscore)(some other letters). am i wrong?

Comment: He said that part is "String with underscores", so that may be many underscores.

Comment: @BharathNaidu So clearly specify your problem in your question next time. My answer is correct based on the clues you have given so far!

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
String token[] = myString().split("_");
String resultString = "";

for(int a=0; a<token.length-1 ;a++){

   if(a == token.length-2)
   resultString = resultString+token[a]
   else
   resultString = resultString+token[a]+"_";


}
```

the `resultString` would be your desired string in every case

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to extract the data:

```
String input = "abc_2012-10-18-05-37-23_prasad_hv_Complete";
String output = input.replaceAll("(?i)^[a-z]+_[^_]+_(\\w+)_[a-z]+$", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try appending the strings again if you exactly know the location of them and if you are sure that locations are constant.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand by your question is that you want 3rd element to (n-1)th element of the String split by "_" to come as it is (where n is the length of array formed after splitting). So, the code would be like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StringSplit {
    public static final String test = "abc_2012-10-18-05-37-23_prasad_hv_Complete";
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String[] data = test.split("_");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
        String aim = data[2];
        for(int i=3;i<data.length-1;i++){
            aim+="_"+data[i];
        }
        System.out.println(aim);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expression. That will result in something like that:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*[0-9]_(.*)_Complete");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("abc_2012-10-18-05-37-23_prasad_hv_Complete");
matcher.find();
String group = matcher.toMatchResult().group(1);
```